# how to create Permanent alias from script

Tags: bash, alias

Please advice how to do the following magic  ( I have linux red-hat machine – 5.4 )

I created the script in the following path:

```
        /usr/cti/my_scripts/MAGIC.bash
```

I want to run this script from evry dir in my linux by alias name – **M**

For example

Under /tmp or /usr/or /var or evry dir
When I type **M** , then it will run the script /usr/cti/my_scripts/MAGIC.bash

Please advice what the steps that need to configure in my linux machine?

**EXAMPLE**

under /usr

when I enter - M

then it will run the script - **/usr/cti/my_scripts/MAGIC.bash**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your "~/.bashrc" or "~/.bash_profile" to include the alias command.

Add this line to your profile:

```
alias M="/usr/cti/my_scripts/MAGIC.bash"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have ruby installed, use [aka](http://github.com/ytbryan/aka) to create permanent alias on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alias in `.bashrc`.
But that works only from interactive shells, not in shell scripts.

To make it work in scripts too, you can make a symlink in a directory that is in `PATH`, for example in `$HOME/bin` directory. (Create it if missing, could be that it is included into `PATH` automatically on next login.)

```
cd ~/bin
ln -s /path/to/M-script.sh M
```