# make custom commands on android 4.4.2

Tags: shell-script, command-line, environment-variables, alias

I want to program and debug in my android phone. To do that I downloaded c4droid and it's gcc plugin.
after a lot of tries I understood that `gcc` is in directory `/data/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/gcc/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`, and `gdb` in `/data/data/com.n0n3m4.droidc/files/gcc/debugger/gdb` (the paths contain the file names).

Because those gcc and gdb isn't regular ones, I can't just type `gcc` or `gdb` to execute it. But I want to use those commands..

I tried to solve this problem in several ways:

1. I tried to add the paths to the `$PATH` variable using `set` and `export`, but it doesn't give me to do so (but without warnings).
2. I tried to add links to the paths in the `$PATH`. but it doesn't give me to do so.
3. I tried to use `alias` to make new commands. It works, but only for the same user in the same terminal, and after exiting, the alias canceled.
4. I tried to make script with the 2 `alias`es to make them easier to run. but even the script runs currently, the `alias`es didn't applied.

So... How do I make `alias`es? or what can I do insted? Do you know why one or more of my tries didn't work for me?

Comment: Aliases are disabled for noninteractive shells. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases

Comment: @muru this answer me only no. 4

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 1 or 2, and regarding 3, I suppose you didn't save it in your .bashrc: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155718/70524

Answer (score 0):

Try using [C4droid-Shell](https://github.com/fann95/C4droid-Shell), and use `$CC` instead of `gcc`.